# Read and write a number from a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, int

Every time I try to write an int variable to a txt file it says I can't write numbers to the text file, code:

```
f = open("money.txt", "w+")
#other code to roll the slot machine
money = money - 1`
f.truncate()
f.write(money)
f.close()
```

When I convert the money variable to a string it just says in the txt file: `100-1` as in you start of with 100 but you - 1 because you rolled the slot machine.

And when I try to read that text file to become the money variable it makes it into a string so I do:

```
f = open(int("money.txt", "w+"))
money = f.readlines()
```

But then it says you can't make the money variable an int.

**Any help will be much appreciated**

Comment: opening a file with `w+` mode will delete the contents of the file before reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you open a file and then read as int not open as int and also not for writing but for reading...

```
open(int("money.txt", "w+"))
```

should be

```
open("money.txt", "r")
```

and then read ints...

e.g.

```
NUMBER_FILE = "number.txt"


def writeInt(filename, integer):
    """Write a number to a file"""
    with open(filename, "w") as fo:
        fo.write("%d" % integer)


def readInt(filename):
    """read the contents of a file"""
    with open(filename, "r") as fi:
        return fi.read()


def main():
    writeInt(NUMBER_FILE, 42)
    print readInt(NUMBER_FILE)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```